# How to update the total number of prints in the MS Access database with Dapper in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq, ms-access

I'm trying to update the total number of prints in the MS Access database table with Dapper in VB.NET

Every time I do an event on the button, I want to increase the number by 1.

I have the code below, but this is still wrong. Please guide me.

Thanks

```
Dim pservice As New PeopleService()    
Private Sub BtnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnPrint.Click
        Try
            Dim objprint = New People With {
               .Numberofprints = +1,
               .Transno = TextBox1.Text}
            pservice.UpdatePeoplePrint(objprint)
        Catch err As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

Public Class People
    Public Property Transno() As String
    Public Property Numberofprints() As Integer
End Class

Public Class PeopleService
    Public Sub UpdatePeoplePrint(ByVal Obj As People)
        Dim sql = $"UPDATE People Set People.Numberofprints = {Obj.Numberofprints} WHERE [People.Transno] = '{Obj.Transno}';"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            _conn.Execute(sql)
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Table : `people`

| Transno | Numberofprints |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1 |
| 1001 |  |
| 1003 |  |

Desired output

| Transno | Numberofprints |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 2 |
| 1001 | 1 |
| 1003 | 1 |

Comment: "still wrong" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? What debugging have you done?

Comment: @June7 , `still wrong` so every time I run it the value remains `1` should add up or be cumulative of the values `1`

Comment: Why not just `People.Numberofprints = People.Numberofprints + 1` in the update statement?

Comment: What makes you think `.Numberofprints += 1` in the object initializer could return any value other than `1`? The default value of the integer property which is `0` + `1`? To make it work this way, you need to get first the `MAX(Numberofprints)` value from the db, assign it to the property, and add `1`. As mentioned, you just need to: `"UPDATE People SET Numberofprints = Numberofprints + 1 WHERE Transno = ?"`. Add command parameter for `?`. ex. `cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = TextBox1.Text`. Then call `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Comment: @GertArnold ,Thank you, you are right I just need to change the SQL code to be like this `UPDATE People Set People.Numberofprints = People.Numberofprints+{Obj.Numberofprints} WHERE [People.Transno] = '{Obj.Transno}';`

Comment: @dr.null , Thank you, you are right. just like you suggested so I just changed the sql code to be like this `UPDATE People Set People.Numberofprints = People.Numberofprints+{Obj.Numberofprints} WHERE [People.Transno] = '{Obj.Transno}';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this syntax:

```
.Numberofprints += 1,
```

and this line should probably read:

```
Public Property Transno() As String
```

**Addendum**

I see it now. You miss a (static?) *variable* to increment, like:

```vb
   Dim PrintCount As Integer

   PrintCount = <some value>

' and then:

        PrintCount += 1
        Try
            Dim objprint = New People With {
               .Numberofprints = PrintCount,
               .Transno = TextBox1.Text}
            pservice.UpdatePeoplePrint(objprint)
        Catch err As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: thank you for your answers . `Public Property Transno() As String` sorry I mistyped this . `.Numberofprints += 1,` for this I have an error `Expression expected and '=' expected (object initializer)`

Comment: No, that won't work. See edited answer, please.

Comment: thank you for the answer but it doesn't work because the solution has to change the sql code to be like this `UPDATE People Set People.Numberofprints = People.Numberofprints+{Obj.Numberofprints} WHERE [People.Transno] = '{Obj.Transno}';`

Comment: I'm not familiar with dapper, so I can't help on that, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it has also helped me and  just need to make changes to the SQL code `UPDATE People Set People.Numberofprints = People.Numberofprints+{Obj.Numberofprints} WHERE [People.Transno] = '{Obj.Transno}';` like this